# expected substitution value for custom inline macro to be of type Inline; got String

Tags: asciidoctor

I am trying to update my macro to use AsciidoctorJ `2.0.0`. I have a macro extending `InlineMacroProcessor` that creates a link or a text depending on the configuration.

To create a link, I can do:

```java
String linkUrl, linkText;
//TODO init the variables

// Define options for an 'anchor' element:
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.put("type", ":link");
options.put("target", linkUrl);

// Create the 'anchor' node:
PhraseNode inline = createPhraseNode(parent, "anchor", linkText, attributes, options);
return inline;
```

I would like to just insert some text to the document.

**Option 1.** return just a String (as with the previous version of AsciidoctorJ):

```java
String linkText;
//TODO init the linkText variable.

return linkText;
```

It works but I get this log entry:

```
INFO: expected substitution value for custom inline macro to be of type Inline; got String
```

Which is implying that I am doing something wrong with the new API.

---

**Option 2:** I have tried to create a `PhraseNode` of type "text" (I invented this)

```java
String linkText;
//TODO init the linkText variable.

PhraseNode inline = createPhraseNode(parent, "text", linkText, attributes, options);
return inline;
```

But then I get:

```
org.asciidoctor.jruby.internal.AsciidoctorCoreException: org.jruby.exceptions.NoMethodError: (NoMethodError) undefined method `convert_inline_text' for #<Asciidoctor::Converter::Html5Converter:0x10b4e7f8>
Did you mean?  convert_inline_button
               convert_inline_quoted
               convert_inline_menu
               convert_inline_image
               convert_inline_break
               convert_inline_kbd
```

So what is the correct way to create an Inline that contains just a string?

Comment: I have created https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj/issues/821 to discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a String, you can use:

```java
PhraseNode inline = createPhraseNode(parent, "quoted", linkText, attributes, options);
return inline;
```